# Dataloader = CSV = Numbers = Scientific Notation

Tags: data-loader, csv, excel, merge

Dataloader requires CSV Files. When I convert my files to CSV it changes the numbers to "Scientific Notions":

Before:

[image: 490000501404]

After:

[image]

Then they show up in Salesforce as Scientific Notions "4.90001E+11".

The only workaround that i've found is, Format the numbers in Excel to "Custom = 0", then dont open the file again, then insert the data with dataloader.

Is this really the only way to proper way to achieve this? Or is there a better way?

The main reason I ask is because I'm merging 500,000+ rows of data from one Org to another and all of that data will be broken down in roughly 20-30 spread sheets. :\

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Dataloader, I believe, that's the best option (You are already doing it). DON'T open the file at all. You can try ETL tools, such as Informatica , Jitterbit etc

Comment: agreed. Do ALL of your work in xls and then save 2 files: datatoload_test.csv with all but the top 5 data row. datatoload_test.csv with the top 5 rows.NEVER open the csv files

Comment: "all but the top 5 data row", What does that mean?

Comment: He simply means, one file has 5 rows in for a test. The second file with all your data has everything, but as you’ve already loaded in the first 5 rows as a test - remove these from the second file

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom formula field using TEXT(BigNumberField__c) and exported that.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the CSV's with Notepad or any text editor
or open a blank workbook and use the option from the picture below and open the extracted CSV
[image]